# mbstring impossible to access while installing laravel with composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm a student in computing, and have a project to do in php.

In order to do it, I want to install laravel as a framework, unfortunately, I'm completely unable to do it, because of a simple error that show everytime I tried to run "composer install" or "composer update". The error is the following :

- laravel/framework v5.3.* requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.

I'm using MAMP as a server, and I'm running it on Windows 8.

I already try several answer I found while I browsed for a solution, none of them were succesful.

- I already uncommented the "extension=php_mbstring.dll" from my php.ini.
- I checked my phpinfo() and the php.ini used is the right one.
- I added my "ext" folder and it's path to the PATH of windows.

Can someone please help me ? I really don't know what to do in order to be able to install laravel for my project..

Sorry if my English is not perfect, I'm a French student.

Comment: Is it the correct php.ini? Did you check phpinfo() from the command line, or via a browser? (composer is running from the command line)

Comment: Did you restart Apache after you un-commented?

Comment: Yes I restarted Apache after I un-commented.

Comment: Mark, I did it in a Browser, I will try in command line

Comment: It seems like I don't have any php.ini file loaded. I used the "phpinfo()" method, and it show me my version of php, but not the php.ini file load. How can I load it ?

Comment: @ThomasJanowskyj Where your php.ini file located? Is under /MAMP/conf/yourphpversion/php.ini or MAMP/bin/php/yourphpversion/conf/php.ini?

Comment: MAMP/bin/php/myphpversion/conf/php.ini